# Wrapping function to use different paremetres in python

Tags: python, random, scipy

I want to generate gamma distributed random variables with [scipy.stats.gamma.rvs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html)

However, the API accepts shape and scale parameter as input and I want to use mean and standard deviation as input.

I could write a wrapper, that would get mean and std as input, computed scale and shape and than used gamma.rvs to generate the random variable. But I expect many calls of this function, so I would prefer if I didn't have to do the computation each time.

I came up with the following solution:

```
from scipy.stats import gamma


def gamma_rvs_generator(mu, sigma):
    var = sigma ** 2
    scale = var / mu
    a = mu / scale
    return lambda: gamma.rvs(a=a, scale=scale)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gen = gamma_rvs_generator(10, 10)
    print(gen())
```

Which works exactly just as I want it to work. But I wanted to ask, if there were any better / more pythonic solutions to this.

Comment: an alternative way would be editing the API but well, that's not the case.  By the way, why are you using `lambda`?

Comment: @magicleon That makes it a function with `0` arguments that can be repeatedly invoked, production a different random number each time. Without the `lambda` it would return a single random number, and hence require the wrapper to be rerun with every new random number.

Comment: oh, like a constructor? Nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel - but that is a matter of taste - it would be more Pythonic to take advantage of `rv_frozen` objects:

```
from scipy.stats import gamma


def gamma_alt(mu, sigma):
    var = sigma ** 2
    scale = var / mu
    a = mu / scale
    return gamma(a=a, scale=scale)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gen = gamma_alt(10, 10)
    print(gen.rvs())
```

Note the call to `gamma` itself, not `gamma.rvs`. Advantage: your gamma_alt behaves more like a "normal" scipy stats citizen. For example, you get not only `rvs` but automatically also `pfd`, `cfd`, etc.